# Showing holomorphy of integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L^1$ with compact support.

I want to show that $\hat f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C, f(z):=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-ixz}d\lambda(x), $ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C$ and I was wondering if I can do it like this:

Let $U_a:=\{z \in \mathbb C: -a<Im(z)<a\}$ and $g(x,z):=f(x)e^{-ixz}$

1) $x\mapsto g(x,z)$ is integrable for all $z \in U_a$: $f$ is integrable and vanishes outside of its support. On the (compact) support $x\mapsto e^{-ixz}$ is integrable because it is continuous. Therefore $x\mapsto g(x,z)$ is integrable for all $z \in U_a$.

2) $z \mapsto g(x,z)$ is holomorphic because for a fixed $x$ $f(x)$ is just a constant and $z \mapsto e^{-ixz}$ is holomorphic.

3) $|g(x,z)|=|f(x)e^{-ixz}|=|f(x)e^{Im(z)}x|<|f(x)|e^{a|x|}$

which is a integrable function $\mathbb R \to \overline {\mathbb R}$

Therefore $\int_{\mathbb R} g(.,z) d\lambda(.)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ (because $U_a$ was arbitrary) according to the 'holomorphy under the integral' lemma

Comment: Perhaps the fastest way is to show, using the dominated convergence theorem, that $$\int f(x)e^{izx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\int \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)z^n,$$ which defines an entire function.

Comment: @SangchulLee I also thought about that but how exactly does one use the dct to argue the interchange of summation and integration? We always used the dct only for a series $f_n$ of functions

Comment: For each *fixed* $z$, you can consider $s_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(izx)^k}{k!}f(x)$. If $f(x)=0$ a.e. outside $[-R,R]$, then $s_n$'s are dominated by the integrable function $e^{R|z|}|f(x)|$ and converges pointwise to $e^{izx}f(x)$. So, one can apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by arguing that $\hat{f}(\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx$ is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$, which follows from the dominated convergence theorem. Then you can apply Morera's theorem by showing that $\int_{\Delta}\hat{f}(\lambda)d\lambda=0$ for all triangles in $\mathbb{C}$, which follows by interchanging the order of integration using Fubini's Theorem:
$$
        \int_{\Delta}\hat{f}(\lambda)d\lambda=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\int_{\Delta}e^{-ix\lambda} d\lambda dx = 0.
$$
The conclusion of Morera's theorem is that $\hat{f}$ is an entire function.